# What's the default score function in validation_curve in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm running the following line of code:

```
validation_curve(PolynomialRegression(),X,y,
                 param_name='polynomialfeatures__degree',
                 param_range=degree,cv=7)
```

And, when I draw the validation_curve I get very negative scores for higher degrees. When I checked the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html?highlight=validation_curve#sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve), it stated

> scoring:str or callable, default=None A str (see model evaluation
> documentation) or a scorer callable object / function with signature
> scorer(estimator, X, y).

I'm just wondering what is the default score function in validation_curve in sklearn? If it's None, then how can they compute a score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It defaults to the `score` method of the estimator, which in turn is often either accuracy (classification) or R2 (regression).

In the [source for `validation_curve`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L1628), it calls `check_scorer`, which [in part contains](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L444):

```py
    elif scoring is None:
        if hasattr(estimator, 'score'):
            return _passthrough_scorer
```

where `_passthrough_scorer` [just wraps](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L395) the estimator's `score`:

```py
def _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs):
    """Function that wraps estimator.score"""
    return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
```